# CPU recommendation

Tags: cpu, computer-building, cpu-cores

I have to build a PC to use a desktop application (a WPF one). Then, in this PC I will have to run a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance, host a WCF services project via IIS, run Reporting Services Server and run the application.

Thats why I need to know what processor will be better for these needs:

I can afford: AMD FX-8150 8-core or Intel I5 2500K.

I know Intel proccesors are really fast, but maybe in the future another PC will be using this PC WCF services, and I thought more cores will be better. Sadly, I just find game benchmarks comparing these CPUs.

Comment: Why choose a processor that's over two years old with an obsolete socket design if building from scratch? If you are going down the Intel route you'd be much better off building an LGA 1150 system as the newest CPU's you can get for the price of a 2500K should be faster, unless you have found a clearance bargain somewhere.

Comment: @James Thanks for your answer. I´m from Argentina, and hardware is REALLY expensive. This is what my budget can afford. An I3 Ivy bridge is another possibility.

Comment: @James - Haswell parts would come at a premium price point.

Comment: @Ramhound: The cheapest I have seen the 2500K in the UK is around £150 - for that money you can buy a Haswell i5 4670K which is significantly faster. Of course that may not be the same in other countries, and second-hand ones will be cheaper.

Comment: @Ramhound thats awesome, but here that I5 doubles the price of the I5 2500K :S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the CPU probably won't be the bottleneck; SQL, WCF, and IIS are i/o, memory, and network intensive but don't really call for much processing power (though they *can* benefit from parallelism, which is not the same as saying they *will* benefit from parallelism). You should worry more about your RAID controller, a good SATA controller (or SCSI if you're feeling old-school), your ethernet card, your bandwidth, etc.

That said, the AMD line you mentioned ("Bulldozer") was designed with power and heat efficiency in mind, so unless you have power and heat constraints that doesn't really help you. But the CPU (within certain reasonable limits) isn't going to be what limits performance here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it the AMD CPU the way to go then?

Comment: Well, sure, but my point was the CPU you choose isn't really going to be all that important as long as it's reasonably modern and multi-core. Your real issues will be disk i/o and the network.